# Why do these Warhammer 40,000 stratagems use slightly different wording?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In 10th edition Warhammer 40,000, the counter offensive stratagem can we used "when an enemy unit has fought" while the Adeptus Mechanicum venegful fallout strategem can be used when "an enemy unit has resolved its attacks".

What is the functional difference between these two wordings, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timing "when an enemy unit has fought" is after the three steps a unit takes when it activates in the fight phase: pile-in, make melee attacks, consolidate. The timing "when an enemy unit has resolved its attacks" would be before they consolidate, if it appeared on a stratagem usable in the fight phase.